# Generic type constraint for numerical type only

Tags: ios, generics, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a type constraint for a generic class (in Swift) that will limit the generic types to numeric types only. For instance Double, Int, etc., but not string. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can specify type constraints (using both classes and protocols) for a generic class (same syntax applies to functions) using angle brackets:

```
class Foo<T: Equatable, U: Comparable> { }
```

To specify more than one requirement on a single type, use a `where` clause:

```
class Foo<T: UIViewController where T: UITableViewDataSource, T: UITextFieldDelegate> { }
```

However, it doesn't look like you can specify optional requirements in a generic parameter clause, so one possible solution is to create a protocol that all the numeric types implement via extensions and then constrain your class on that requirement:

```
protocol Numeric { }

extension Float: Numeric {}
extension Double: Numeric {}
extension Int: Numeric {}


class NumberCruncher<C1: Numeric> {
    func echo(num: C1)-> C1 {
        return num
    }
}

NumberCruncher<Int>().echo(42)
NumberCruncher<Float>().echo(3.14)
```

Comment: I thought it may have to be something like this but I was just hoping there would already be something built in. Not to difficult to implement though. Thanks.

Comment: Generics provide promise, but using Generics for numerical algorithms has many pitfalls.  The gymnastics to provide common access to the zero of a type (they didn't think to include a zero() class function for all number types) is only one of the issues that you may encounter.  The architectural differences between integer and floating point numbers preclude generic programming for many numeric algorithms.

Answer (score 12):

`Strideable` is the *smallest* standard protocol that every standard number type conforms to, but it also has a few more types conforming to it.
http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/Strideable/hierarchy/

Or you can use `IntegerType` and `FloatingPointType`.

Comment: Or now in Swift 3-- `Integer` instead of `IntegerType`

Answer (score 1):

As talked about [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md) and [here](https://swiftunboxed.com/protocols/numeric/), the `Numeric` protocol is now part of Swift 4, so - for example - you can overload `+` for numeric tuples as follows:

```
func +<T : Numeric> (x: (T, T), y: (T, T)) -> (T, T) { 
     return (x.0 + y.0, x.1 + y.1) 
}

(1,1) + (2,3) // (3, 4) : (Int, Int)
(1.25, 1.5) + (2.5, 2.25) // (3.75, 3.75) : (Double, Double)
```