# Create a .toString() extension for all numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to create a .toString method extension for numbers using Swift just for fun. It works if I specify Int, or Double, etc. It doesn't work right out of the box with NSNumber since it is an object in itself, right? Is there a way to 'catch all' ints floats doubles etc? Some base number class of some sort?

I see this other answer, but I don't want to create a custom type/protocol, just plug this on any 'number'.
[Generic type constraint for numerical type only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073135/apple-swift-generic-type-constraint-for-numerical-type-only)

```
extension Int {
    func toString () -> String {
        return String (self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need toString when Swift already has the .description extension for Int and Double ?

Comment: Are you intending to create a `.toString` for *everything* in Swift?  This isn't Java or C# or whatever other languages use `.toString`.  It's called `.description` and `.debugDescription`.  Also, they're readonly properties, not methods.

Comment: .description can be misleading, I would prefer to have a function called toString. Easier to remember and easier to view the code later.

Comment: How is `.description` misleading?  How is `.toString` easier to remember and "easier to view the code later"?  **EVERY** built-in Swift type has a `.description` property.  **NO** built-in Swift type has a `.toString` property.

Comment: Geez chillax. I personally think that the name description is not self explaining at all that it converts the value to a string. At first one could think its a description of the Datatype or something like that.

Comment: @nhgrif For example for a String there is a function called toInt(). So if there is a function with to + type then why have description only to get a string. That part is confusing of apple to do.

Comment: Apple didn't do it.  It comes from Objective-C, and it was in the language before it was "Apple's language".  Also, because `toString` is actually more confusing then you want to admit.  Is `toString` supposed to be an actual string representation of the object, or does it contain some sort of debug information only intended to be printed to the console?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. You can use Swift native `description` property for `Double`, `Int`, and `NSNumber`s:

```
Int(1).description                            // "1"
Double(2.0).description                       // "2.0"
NSNumber(double: 3.0).doubleValue.description // "3.0"
```

Comment: Not necessary to add to the answer, but `.description` exists for *every* built-in Swift type, including **several** other numeric types like `UInt`, `Float`, `CGFloat`, `NSInteger`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Bool`, etc., etc., etc.... if it's a Swift built-in type, it's got a `.description` property.  +1

Comment: Just to add, description is from the Printable protocol.

Comment: thanks for that, .description does fit the bill. altho, i did mention this was for fun -- or in another words, a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
let x : Int = 33  
let stringValue = "\(x)"
```

or

```
let stringValue = String(x)
```

or

```
let stringValue = Int(x).description
```